# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when movie played the second time

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am using `mpmovieplayercontroller` to play a movie in my game. When the user taps the screen I run a method that replaces the current layer containing the movie with the game main menu. It works fine the first time, but when I try to play the video the second time from the main menu I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the line

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController");
```

in the main.m.

Please find the relevant code below.

```
-(void)playVideo    {
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"mp4"]];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

// Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];

if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {
    // Use the new 3.2 style API
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    // This does blows up in cocos2d, so we'll resize manually
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];       
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, winSize.width, winSize.height);    //width and height are swapped after rotation        
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:moviePlayer.view ];

    [moviePlayer play];

    UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = (id)self;
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

    [tapGestureRecognizer release];

} else {
    // Use the old 2.0 style API
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [moviePlayer play];
}

}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

[moviePlayer stop];
[[MenuManager sharedMenuManager] runMenu:kMMenuLayer];

}

// this enables you to handle multiple recognizers on single view
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
return YES;
}

-(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
moviePlayer = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:moviePlayer];

// If the moviePlayer.view was added to the openGL view, it needs to be removed
if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {
    [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    CCLOG(@"this block is okay");
}

[moviePlayer release];
}
```

Please help.

Comment: to see the offending line of code set an exception breakpoint https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: the exception breakpoint is also pointing to the same line.

Comment: enable zombie objects in the scheme

Comment: try setting moviePlayer = nil after you release it to prevent potentially dangling pointer

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: sorry for not replying, I left this issue for a while but I've still been unable to solve it. After enabling the zombie scheme I got the following in the log  `[Instructions handleTap:]: message sent to deallocated instance`. I also set moviePlayer = nil but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @Till: I converted the code to ARC but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting the message is sent to a deallocated instance is because you've not removed the tapGestureRecognizer from the view. I believe your MenuManager singleton replaces the current layer with another, but since the tapGestureRecognizer is still part of the view it will try to access the handleTap, which by this time is deallocated. Add the following line before singleton call in handleTap.

```
 [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] removeGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```